# Was the American interview at the end of "La Vie En Rose" real?

Tags: dialogue, realism, biopic, la-vie-en-rose

In one of the final scenes of the Oscar-winning Edith Piaf biopic *La Vie En Rose* (2007), a now elderly Edith is sitting on a beach and approached by an American reporter conducting an interview for an American magazine.

A transcript of the interview can be seen [here](https://jasmineangelique.blogspot.com/2010/03/la-vie-en-rose.html).

Was this interview real, and were Edith Piaf's notoriously pithy answers to them real?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this interview with the director **Olivier Dahan** in The Villanovan](http://www.villanovan.com/interview-with-director-of-la-vie-en-rose/article_b1ac011f-ac12-5126-b81e-bf7a719b7cf9.html), the scene was invented, but the interview appears to be real:

> Natalie Smith: There is one scene that occurs between Edith and a reporter on a beach
>   in California that you said was fictional, while everything else in
>   the film really happened. Why did you include it?
>
> Olivier Dahan: **The interview was real. Ninety-nine percent of the film was true,
>   except for the last sequence on the beach. This I just imagined.** Maybe
>   at this point I needed something outside the balconies of the theatre
>   because so much of it was dark.

Comment: Interesting, so it seems the only real source of it is from the director himself. I really wanted to read the interview directly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hashim I've been looking for the interview but when I search the web all it throws up are transcripts of this scene. Then again, what is the chance that interviews with Piaf are easily found online?